# Merge two Combine Arrays into a Single Array

Tags: arrays, swift, combine, flatmap

I have two types

```
let left: Future<[Int]>
let right: Future<[Int]>
```

How can I combine these so I have one contiguous 1D array?

Using `append` and `merge` create 2D arrays and there's no clear information. Is really the best way to collect the 2D arrays and then use a flatMap inside of a flatMap like:

```
.collect().flatMap { arrays in arrays.flatMap { $0 } }
```

there has to be a better way.

Comment: what does "combine arrays" mean here? If you have `[1,4]` emitted from `left`, and `[2,3,5]` - from `right`, what should happen? Do you want to wait until you have both values and the combine into `[1,4,2,3,5]` or do you want to emit values one-by-one?

Comment: @NewDev to your question - these are futures, so the arrays come as a single object, not as a stream individually. The order of left/right or right/left doesn't matter to me :)

Comment: @NewDev to your example here, that would be perfect, but just emit as a single array `[1,4,2,3,5]`.  (The example code I have would produce output as you suggest, I just think there's probably a better way)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have two publishers emitting values that you want to combine somehow, you generally have two types of behavior that you might want: (1) `zip` - wait for each to emit, or (2) `combineLatest` - emit as soon as any one emits a value.

So, in your case, it could be a `zip`

```
left.zip(right)
    .map { (l, r) in l + r)
    .sink { ... }
```

or a `combineLatest`:

```
left.combineLatest(right)
    .map { (l, r) in l + r)
    .sink { ... }
```

They behave the same, if both `left` and `right` emit a single value (e.g. like a `Future` does). So, if `left` emits `[1,4]` and `right` emits `[2,3,5]`, the output would be `[1,4,2,3,5]`

The difference is what happens after.

With `zip`, when `left` emits the next value, say `[11,44]`, there would be no output until `right` emits a value, say `[22,33,55]`, and then the output would be: `[11,44,22,33,55]`.

With `combineLatest`, as soon as `left` emits, the output would be `[11,44,2,3,5]` and then when `right` emits, the output would be `[11,44,22,33,55]`

Comment: zip + map was what I was looking for, mainly the `map` function is the key as I was using flatMap and then the `Just` which isn't so good. Thanks!